# Sending a file continuously via netcat/socat

Tags: linux, tcp, raspberry-pi, netcat, socat

I want to send a file from one Raspberry Pi to another continuously (until they are powered off or something). I am sending data from one Pi to an AP, and forwarding that data from that AP to the other Pi. I am using the current code to send the file once (successfully):

Receiver: `socat TCP-LISTEN:4242 /home/pi/Desktop/smth`

Sender: `socat TCP:hostname:4242 /home/pi/Desktop/zeroMega.dat`

The file I'm sending (zeroMega.dat) is a randomly generated file, since I don't care about the data and just need to continuously send (loop) this file of 1 MB from one Pi to the other. How could I do this? I know I probably need to create a script to run this continuously, especially since I need this to run on startup. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Another option may be to use `/dev/zero` as your file and that will keep suppling zeroes forever...

Comment: I created the file zeroMega.dat using `/dev/zero` in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: My point was that if your file is infinitely large you will not have to loop repeatedly because the first file will take forever.

Comment: My file is 1 MB, I chose a random low value because from what I know about Linux systems, they store most things in RAM, which I have 1 GB of. I was initially sending a 1.3 GB file and it was reading directly from the SD card (file was too large to store in RAM), thus limiting my transfer speed. I thought I could loop a 1 MB file so I could have higher transfer speeds due to the file being stored in RAM. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: Reading from `/dev/null` should be able to supply GB/s and also not need any space or bandwidth from your SD card. Try it! `time dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=65536 count=10000000`

Comment: This seems like a good idea, I'm generating the it with 3.2 GB/s. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm currently generating a file full of zeros forever? Could I forward this over a network to my other device if I integrate it into my script? This would mean I don't have to loop a 1 MB file which would probably be better. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly - that was my point. You can just read it and discard it at the other end. Also, on a Pi, the SD card shares the USB babwidth with the network so this will hammer your network even harder.

Comment: One last question, I am generating a file from `/dev/zero` (in my script) as you advised, but my AP seams to go crazy and is not showing traffic, same as my spectrum analyzer. Could I specify the size of the file (as you have above) in the script? I am currently running this `#!/bin/bash
while true; do
echo "press CTRL+C to stop"
dd if=/dev/zero | socat - UDP:right_pi:4244 
done`
I don't know if the parameters of the file are the problem but I can't seem to stream an infinite file yet.

Comment: Yes, you can add a blocksize and a count of blocks. It's hard for me to tell what's going on:-)

Comment: Sorry and thanks, I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it inside an infinite loop:

```
while true; do
  # whatever should be repeated forever
done
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I tried this and while the logic of it seems to be correct, I'm getting an error due to the port I'm using. I have the aforementioned code in my post copied in the "while" example you gave me in two .sh files on both Raspberry Pi's. It seems that when I send my file over the specified port (4242 in this case), I get the error: `Address already in use` I believe this is because after sending the file once, it tries on the same port and sees that there is an existing process there. How could I overcome this? Sending the file over the same port "infinite" times would be perfect.

Comment: Hmm, yes, ports continue to be reserved some time after they are closed. Do you actually want to _store_ the file on the other end? If all you want is generate some traffic, it might be easier to send an infinite stream of data instead. Other commenters seem to have come to the same conclusion :)

Comment: Yes indeed, I do not need to store the info on the other end, in fact, I'm writing it to `/dev/null` on the receiving end. Using UDP instead of TCP gives me some traffic (~15 Mbps). It's not steady though (completely stops for 10 seconds sometimes), but then again it is UDP. Thanks.